# Creating index for WHERE OR

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I have a MySQL Table with `114843213` rows.

It is read-only for me and I want to read it 10000 rows at a time.

I could read it with `OFFSET` and `LIMIT`, but then I would read it in the wrong order (It takes less than a second).

This is my query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM `AUDIT`
WHERE `AD_TIMESTAMP` > '1970-1-1 10:10:10.0'
   OR (`AD_TIMESTAMP` = '1970-1-1 10:10:10.0' AND `AD_SQLIDENTITY` > 1)
ORDER BY `AD_TIMESTAMP` ASC, `AD_SQLIDENTITY` ASC
LIMIT 10000 OFFSET 0;
```

So, I do need to read it by timestamp ascending, and If the timestamp for two or more entries is equal, then read it by its ID (`AD_SQLIDENTITY`).

**This takes about 4 minutes per request.**

I have created an Index like so:

```sql
create index AUDIT_AD_SQLIDENTITY_AD_TIMESTAMP_index
    on AUDIT (AD_SQLIDENTITY ASC , AD_TIMESTAMP ASC)
```

But when I use explain on the `SELECT` above I can see that it doesn't get used - so my index is not good enough. I also tried a view, but it takes 5 minutes to render.

How can I increase the performance of my `SELECT`?

**Edit: more info**
This is the explain:

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "select_type": "SIMPLE",
    "table": "IdisAuditEntity",
    "partitions": null,
    "type": "ALL",
    "possible_keys": "AUDIT_AD_SQLIDENTITY_AD_TIMESTAMP_index",
    "key": null,
    "key_len": null,
    "ref": null,
    "rows": 103361870,
    "filtered": 35.55,
    "Extra": "Using where; Using filesort"
  }
]
```

Schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `AUDIT` (
  `AD_ID` char(32) COLLATE latin1_german1_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `AD_SQLIDENTITY` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AD_USER` varchar(120) COLLATE latin1_german1_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `AD_TIMESTAMP` datetime(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AD_FIELD` varchar(60) COLLATE latin1_german1_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `AD_HOSTNAME` varchar(80) COLLATE latin1_german1_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `AD_APPLICATIONNAME` varchar(120) COLLATE latin1_german1_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `AD_OLDVAL` varchar(250) COLLATE latin1_german1_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `AD_NEWVAL` varchar(250) COLLATE latin1_german1_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `AD_TABLE` varchar(60) COLLATE latin1_german1_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `AD_DS_ID` varchar(60) COLLATE latin1_german1_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `AD_TABLE_SQL_IDENTITY` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AD_COLUMNS_UPDATED` longtext COLLATE latin1_german1_ci,
  `AD_TYPE` varchar(60) COLLATE latin1_german1_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `AD_DS_ID2` varchar(60) COLLATE latin1_german1_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `AD_TS1` datetime(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AD_TS2` datetime(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AD_TS3` datetime(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AD_L1` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AD_L2` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AD_C1` varchar(200) COLLATE latin1_german1_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `AD_C2` varchar(200) COLLATE latin1_german1_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `AD_NA_ID` varchar(30) COLLATE latin1_german1_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `AUDIT_AD_SQLIDENTITY_AD_TIMESTAMP_index` (`AD_SQLIDENTITY`,`AD_TIMESTAMP`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_german1_ci
```

Comment: @nbk `AD_TIMESTAMP`, `AD_SQLIDENTITY` and?

Comment: a sorry i missread, your query uses an or that makes no sense, the second is identical to the first, so remove it and then the index should be used, if not Force the index https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/index-hints.html  but please add the explain to your a question, it is strange that it isn't in there, there must be a cause

Comment: your where clause is equivalent to just `AD_SQLIDENTITY > 1`; did you mean something different?

Comment: if you really do have two OR'd conditions, to use an index you would do two unioned selects, each with a limit 10000 and with a limit 10000 on the union as a whole.

Comment: whenever you ask about performance/indexing, it is helpful to include the output of `show create table yourtablename` for all relevant tables.

Comment: @ysth thanks I indeed made a mistake, corrected it. Do you still suggest to do two union selects?

Comment: no, I would first try rewriting it as `AD_TIMESTAMP >= '1970-1-1 10:10:10.0' AND (AD_TIMESTAMP > '1970-1-1 10:10:10.0' OR AD_SQLIDENTITY > 1)`

Comment: "show create table" presents the schema and indexes in a much much more useful form

Comment: @ysth thanks, edited the question. your suggestion did not improve the query performance (and explain still tells me that the key is not respected)

Comment: I'd say that the order of the columns in the index should match the order of the columns in the ORDER BY clause.

Comment: Reverse the order of the columns in your index. I *think* that should fix things. If that works I'll submit a full answer explaining what's going on.

Comment: Thanks that was it- now I'm at 7 seconds, which is good enough for me :)

Comment: @Mihe - In this case, the order of the index columns needs to match the "continue in the column pair of TS+ID")

Comment: @RickJames, thank you. As I'm not a native speaker, it's not that easy to find correct and concise words :-)

Comment: I discuss it further here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#iterating_through_a_compound_key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recognize that WHERE as one of two ways to walk through a 2-column index, remembering where you left off.  Contrary to the usual advice against `OR`, this one *should* be well optimized.

Every table should have a `PRIMARY KEY`.

For the query in question, you need the two columns in the opposite order in an index.

If you are guaranteeing that AD_SQLIDENTITY is unique, then have

```
PRIMARY KEY(AD_SQLIDENTITY),
INDEX(AD_TIMESTAMP, AD_SQLIDENTITY)
```

(and get rid of the current KEY)

If it is not unique, then add

```
ID BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY(AD_TIMESTAMP, AD_SQLIDENTITY, ID),
INDEX(ID)
```

(and keep the current KEY *if* it is useful for any other query).

Other things to check:  How much RAM?  How big is the table?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?

Comment: why should every table have a `PRIMARY KEY` ?

Comment: Long story that has been told many times.  It involves being able to uniquely identify each row (especially useful for `UPDATE` and `DELETE`).  You will get a 6-byte PK if you don't have one, but it can't be used directly.  (It is not an absolute requirement for _this_ Question.)

Comment: @InsOp - Also, by using the PK instead of a secondary index, it will prevent 10000 lookups to get the "*" in `SELECT *`.  I think either of my suggestions will achieve that optimization.